# where does CMAKE get environment variables?

Tags: bash, cmake

If I type in console:

```
$ echo $COCOS_ROOT
```

I get the correct path because I have this variable defined in my .bashrc file. However, when I execute this code,

```
SET(COCOS_HOME "$ENV{COCOS_ROOT}")
if (COCOS_HOME)
    message( STATUS "COCOS2D installed in" ${COCOS_HOME})
else()
    message( WARNING "COCOS2D is undefined")
endif()
```

The environment var is not defined. If I define the ENV var in console making:

```
$ export COCOS_ROOT=/path/to/cocos
```

Then the script is correctly set with cocos2D path.

My question is: where do I need to define the env vars to be found by cmake?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` file you need to export the `COCOS_ROOT` variable, otherwise it's not passed to child processes:

```
export COCOS_ROOT=/path/to/cocos
```

and not

```
COCOS_ROOT=/path/to/cocos
```

Your COCO_ROOT is available in your shell because the `.bashrc` file is loaded when your shell starts.

Comment: Why did you underline the difference between the command with and without export? In the question it was already put correctly...

Comment: I mean you should be using export in your bashrc as well.

Comment: And why on earth you should not? :)

Comment: Well, even without export the variable will get the correct value in the shell, it just won't pass to child processes. And I'm pretty that's the problem here.